# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes - GPU has fallen off the bus

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, freeze, crash

ever since I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my notebook, the system freezes from time to time. Sometimes after 5min, sometimes after 12h. I read already many similar posts here, but nothing could fix this so far. The syslog shows this:

```
[409.510638] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-9fa50d45-1ce5-82a4-9edd-436827ce0bb2 
[409.510640] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, pid=2976, GPU has fallen off the bus. 
[409.510641] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: GPU has fallen off the bus. 
[409.510694] NVRM: A GPU crash dump has been created. If possible, please run 
[409.510694] NVRM: nvidia-bug-report.sh as root to collect this data before 
[409.510694] NVRM: the NVIDIA kernel module is unloaded. 
[421.797707] sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled. 
[421.869714] sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled. 
[422.453723] sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled. 
[422.933751] sysrq: Emergency Sync 
[422.935343] Emergency Sync complete 
[423.325743] sysrq: Emergency Remount R/O
```

When this happens I can't do anything. If I press ctrl+s in my current application the file is not saved. I can't open tty. The only things which are working are "REISUB" and "REISUO". So I can't execute nvidia-bug-report.sh before the reboot.

I am running the latest nvidia driver, I had the problem ever since, I guess I started with 440:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 495.44       Driver Version: 495.44       CUDA Version: 11.5     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P620         Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P3    N/A /  N/A |    309MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2066      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                200MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2550      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               40MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3205      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       66MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

On this pc I used windows for only very short periods, but I never had a problem there, so I would think it is rather a driver issue than a hardware defect.
Do you think it would make sense to use the intel i7 GPU instead? Is there a simple way to deactivate the nvidia GPU in Ubuntu?

I am happy for any hints.
BR Michael

Comment: How and where from did you obtain the 495 driver? It's not in the 18.04 repositories and even Nvidia suggests 470, not 495, for a Quadro P620.

Comment: Usually I just enter "ubuntu-drivers devices" in terminal, a saw it listed there.
495 is available even if the 470 is recommended in this list

Comment: So, as you can see, 470 is "recommended".

Comment: True, but this is not a most recent problem, usually I took the recommended one, which was in the past the latest. I just installed the 495 yesterday but the issue with the freezes is ever since I got this notebook one year ago.